# F#: Assembly reference RDotNet.dll was not found or is invalid

Tags: r, f#, nuget, .net-assembly

While trying to load the RProvider.fsx, I get a error that the Assembly reference RDotNet.dll was not found or is invalid

I'm following this walktrough: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/Statistics-QuickStart.html

Comment: Well, can you find the assembly then?

Comment: This should help: [How does F# Interactive #I command know about project path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673544/how-does-f-interactive-i-command-know-about-project-path) I would also suggest that if you are using VS that you open a F# project, install R using NuGet via VS, add reference in project to R and then open F# Interactive from the project, Then the example should work. The trick to getting it to work is to have the `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ ` set properly.

Comment: I found it on my computer, but for some reason I can't add it to my reference  && @guy coder, I'll try it

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks this worked!

Comment: You should post the exact details as an answer and get yourself some points. Screen shots are good. Also refer back to the other page in the answer. Also do a `printfn __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` to show the invalid one and then the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 15 (I use the free community edition)
Create new F# console project: UseNuGetPackage (Exact steps NOT given)

[image]

Download and [install R](http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/windows/base/)  (Exact steps NOT given)

**Install R Type provider**

In Visual Studio using Solution Explorer
Right click F# project e.g. UseNuGetPackage
Select: Manage NuGet Packages for Solution

[image]

Click Browse
Enter: RProvider
Click check box on the left of Project

[image]

Click Install

[image]

Click OK

The Visual Studio output window shows:

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'RProvider.1.1.15' with respect to project 'UseNuGetPackage', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'RProvider.1.1.15' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'RProvider.1.1.15'
Resolved actions to install package 'RProvider.1.1.15'
Adding package 'DynamicInterop.0.7.4' to folder 'c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\packages'
Added package 'DynamicInterop.0.7.4' to folder 'c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\packages'
Added package 'DynamicInterop.0.7.4' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'DynamicInterop 0.7.4' to UseNuGetPackage
Adding package 'R.NET.Community.1.6.4' to folder 'c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\packages'
Added package 'R.NET.Community.1.6.4' to folder 'c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\packages'
Added package 'R.NET.Community.1.6.4' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'R.NET.Community 1.6.4' to UseNuGetPackage
Adding package 'R.NET.Community.FSharp.1.6.4' to folder 'c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\packages'
Added package 'R.NET.Community.FSharp.1.6.4' to folder 'c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\packages'
Added package 'R.NET.Community.FSharp.1.6.4' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'R.NET.Community.FSharp 1.6.4' to UseNuGetPackage
Adding package 'RProvider.1.1.15' to folder 'c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\packages'
Added package 'RProvider.1.1.15' to folder 'c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\packages'
Added package 'RProvider.1.1.15' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'RProvider 1.1.15' to UseNuGetPackage
========== Finished ==========
```

Notice in the image below the green check mark identifying that the package is installed.

[image]

Notice in the image below the new references for the project.

[image]

To get the following two statements to work we need to verify some paths.

```
#I "../packages/RProvider.1.0.11"
#load "RProvider.fsx"
```

The example given is specific to a version and as we know versions change so check the version of the DLL that will be used.

In the F# project
Right click the RProvider reference
Right click Properties

[image]

[image]

Here is the full path so you don't have to squint

```
c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\packages\RProvider.1.1.15\lib\net40\RProvider.dll
```

The example is using version `RProvider.1.0.11` and we have `RProvider.1.1.15`
so we need to update the line from the example to

```
#I "../packages/RProvider.1.1.15"
```

If you look a lot of examples where you download a package from NuGet and then use it with F# Interactive you will see the same pattern to get it started.

```
#I "../packages/<Name_XYZ>.<Version>"
#load "<Name_XYZ>.fsx"
```

This is because this code assumes that you have used NuGet to install the needed DLLs in a VS project and that the DLLS are in a `packages` directory that is relative to the source code for the project. If you look back at the listing I gave for the output window you will see the copying of the DLLs.

Here they are shown in File Explorer

[image]

So how does F# Interactive know how to find the DLLs when it only has a relative path.

> Now for the magical missing part that we leave out because it is a
>   conspiracy to test newbies. :-)

F# Interactive has the property `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` that gives the location of the source directory in a VS project. This can be seen in F# Interactive with

```
printfn __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
```

which for my example is

```
c:\users\eric\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UseNuGetPackage\UseNuGetPackage
val it : unit = ()
```

if you get a directory containing `AppData` then restart F# Interactive.

This can be checked with File Explorer

[image]

sure enough this is the source directory for the project.

More importantly the path from the source directory to the NuGet packages is

```
../packages
```

So all the paths look good.

Now that we have updated and checked the script lines to load the DLL give it a try.

We get the error:

```
error FS0082: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "RDotNet.FSharp.dll".
```

The problem is the specific versions mentioned in `RProvider.fsx`

```
// Standard NuGet locations for R.NET
#I "../R.NET.Community.1.5.16/lib/net40"
#I "../R.NET.Community.FSharp.0.1.9/lib/net40"
```

If we substitute out `#load "RProvider.fsx"` with

```
#r "../packages/R.NET.Community.1.6.4/lib/net40/RDotNet.dll"
#r "../packages/R.NET.Community.FSharp.1.6.4/lib/net40/RDotNet.FSharp.dll"
#r "../packages/RProvider.1.1.15/lib/net40/RProvider.dll"
#r "../packages/RProvider.1.1.15/lib/net40/RProvider.Runtime.dll"

open RProvider
do fsi.AddPrinter(fun (synexpr:RDotNet.SymbolicExpression) -> synexpr.Print())

open System
open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.graphics
open RProvider.stats
```

The example works. e.g.

```
// Random number generator
let rng = Random()
let rand () = rng.NextDouble()

// Generate fake X1 and X2 
let X1s = [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> 10. * rand () ]
let X2s = [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> 5. * rand () ]

// Build Ys, following the "true" model
let Ys = [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> 5. + 3. * X1s.[i] - 2. * X2s.[i] + rand () ]

let dataset =
    namedParams [
        "Y", box Ys;
        "X1", box X1s;
        "X2", box X2s; ]
    |> R.data_frame

let result = R.lm(formula = "Y~X1+X2", data = dataset)

let coefficients = result.AsList().["coefficients"].AsNumeric()
let residuals = result.AsList().["residuals"].AsNumeric()

let summary = R.summary(result)
summary.AsList().["r.squared"].AsNumeric()

R.plot result
```

Also as Tomas noted in his answer there is a bug with the version numbers in the fsx file, but he was able to update the source code and make a new alpha version.
:)

Hopefully I gave enough detail that the next time you see one of these examples on using a NuGet package with F# Interactive  and have a problem you can resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in `RProvider.fsx` where it references a wrong version of R.NET. The [version 1.1.16-alpha has a fix for this](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharpRProvider/pull/167), but we did not release a new non-beta yet.

Can you check that this works fine if you install 1.1.16-alpha?

Answer (score 0):

The link of @GuyCoder helped me: [How does F# Interactive #I command know about project path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673544/how-does-f-interactive-i-command-know-about-project-path)

I searched the missing .dll files on my computer, and pasted in the parent folder of the source directory. 
After this everything worked fine

```
    #I "../packages/RProvider.1.1.15"
(*
#r "RDotNet.dll"
#r "RDotNet.FSharp.dll"
These 2 are unnecessary*)
#load "RProvider.fsx"


open System
open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.graphics
open RProvider.stats
```

[image: My directory]

EDIT:

I first downloaded the nuget packages Rdotnet & Rdotnet.Fsharp, then I searched on my computer for the dll's, [image]
[image]

Then I copied these files and pasted it in the directory I was working in: [image]

Which you also can find with `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` 
[image]

Comment: The edit is better, but the answer is wrong. You need to delete the files you copied and figure out how to start F# Interactive with a `__SOURCE_DIRCTORY__` set correctly so that the example given from the provider page works. That's what the comment was trying to explain.